# openlayer point symbol from wkt string

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I'd like to represent a series of points each associated with their own wkt string representing the shape of that point at a certain zoom level.

With geoserver, I can do that pretty easily. Something like this for example:

```css
* {
   mark: symbol("wkt://MULTILINESTRING((-0.25 -0.25, -0.125 -0.25), (0.125 -0.25, 0.25 -0.25), (-0.25 0.25, -0.125 0.25), (0.125 0.25, 0.25 0.25))");
}
```

This symbol is relative to the actual coordinate of a point and can be sized up or down with another property.

Is there anything similar with openlayer ?
How can I represent a point with a dynamic polygon shape ?

I'd be interesting to know how to do this with webGL in Openlayer, if it's possible as the data I'm working with contains thousands of points on the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLayers styles have a geometry property (defaults to the feature's geometry but can be overridden) so if you had a WKT geometry string as a property of a point feature you could parse that, translate it relative to the feature's position and use it to style the point:

```
var features = [
  new Feature({
    geometry: new Point([50, 50]),
    mark: "MULTILINESTRING((-0.25 -0.25, -0.125 -0.25), (0.125 -0.25, 0.25 -0.25), (-0.25 0.25, -0.125 0.25), (0.125 0.25, 0.25 0.25))"
  })
];

var parser = new WKT();

var style = new Style({
  stroke = new Stroke({
    width: 2,
    color: 'black'
});

var layer = new VectorLayer({
  source : new VectorSource({
    features: features,
  }),
  style: function(feature) {
    var point = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    var mark = parser.readGeometry(feature.get('mark'));
    mark.translate(point[0], [point[1]);
    style.setGeometry(mark);
    return style;
  }
});
```